# identify groups consecutive True values in pd.Serie

Tags: pandas, boolean

I have a boolean pd.Series.

```
S=pd.Series([True,False,True,True,False])
```

I would need to identify the blocks in S, which are at least 2 consecutive True elements.
If I do

```
np.logical_and(S,S.shift(-1))
```

then I get the right elements but each block is missing one element.
Instead, I would like to get the following

```
pd.Series([False,False,True,True,False])
```

so a `Series` same size as original, with single `True` replaced by `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create unique consecutive groups by compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then count values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) or [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
b = S.ne(S.shift()).cumsum()
c = b.map(b.value_counts()) == 2
```

Or:

```
c = b.groupby(b).transform('size') == 2
```

---

```
print (c)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer.however i still have a problem: you solution returns true also when there are more than 2 consecutive False values

Comment: @00__00__00 - Then change `> 1` to `== 2`, I think need 2 or more, sorry.